# Usergrid: Accessing a resource in Usergrid

Tags: apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

I am running usergrid on my local, I am trying to access an entity I just created, however I seem to having issues inspite of confirming to what is specified in the documentation:

The entity I created is: /summaries/915b986a-78cf-11e4-aa04-eb4bd0e81071

it is preceeded by my API name , which in turn is preceeded by my org name, so it gives me:

```
http://localhost:3000/test-org/test-api/summaries/915b986a-78cf-11e4-aa04-eb4bd0e81071
```

I am not able to reach the entity with the above is there anything I am missing?

-S

Comment: what is the response you get back? And, what response do you get when you request http://localhost:3000/test-org/test-api/summaries?

Comment: Looks to me like you have this correct. Share your output if you can. The format should be:  http://servername/orgname/appname/summaries/uuid or name